# Laravel Eloquent Collection returned as object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Why is my laravel eloquent query returning me an object? Shouldnt the returned data be in the form of an eloquent collection? Which should allow me to use the splice method.

Can someone please explain to me why the data in $location tier 1 is being seen as an object? if anything shouldnt it be an array containing objects? [ object, object] and i am trying to insert an object into this array by index

```
The data contained within $location tier 1 is
[{"id":1,"name":"school","lat":0,"lng":0,"enable_audit":0,"x_axis":0,"y_axis":0,"z_axis":0,"service_provider_id":0,"client_id":313,"description":"school","order":1,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","location_id":1,"parent_id":0},{"id":4,"name":"school","lat":0,"lng":0,"enable_audit":0,"x_axis":0,"y_axis":0,"z_axis":0,"service_provider_id":0,"client_id":313,"description":"school","order":2,"created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","location_id":1,"parent_id":0}]

 $location_tier_1 = LocationTier1::where('location_id','=',$location_id)->orderby('id')->get();
 array_splice($location_tier_1,$i+1,0,$value);
```

[image]

Comment: Eloquent return always an object called Collection, try to: `$location_tier_1= $location_tier_1->toArray(); array_splice($location_tier_1,$i+1,0,$value);` or try to splice it. `$location_tier_1->splice($i+1,0,$value);`

Comment: @Mariano then how would i convert it back to a collection? i still need to use the properties in $location like $location->id

Comment: Well, try ->splice() method of Laravel @Yeo Bryan

Comment: @Mariano use splice to insert into the collection? i did, it reflected that error there

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel collection methods

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$chunk = $collection->splice(2);
// [3, 4, 5]
$collection->all();
// [1, 2]
```